# Anonymous Type based on list of strings

Tags: c#-4.0, anonymous-types

i have a type, let's say

```
class MyType { string A; string B; int C; DateTime D;}
```

I have a list of strings, let's say

```
List<string> columns = new List<string>(){ "A", "C", "D"};
```

I want to create a new type at run time based on property matches to the strings in the columns. Like my new type will be

```
   MyType oldType = new MyType() { 
                   A = "Hello", 
                   B = "World",
                   C = 2013,
                   D = DateTime.Now()
              }
   // it contains ACD as in columns list and corresponding values from oldType
   var newtype = new { 
                   A = "Hello" ,
                   C = 2013,
                   D = DateTime.Now()
                }
```

I am not able to understand what approach I should take other than using emit to create new type. Suggest me something without using reflection or emit.

Comment: How about an anonymous type? Have a look at Linq, it will do the matching as well.

Comment: Yes I need to create anonymous type, as subject says